# Can we use a global deployment/user key in CircleCI (context of private dependencies directly on github)?

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

Every time I add a new project/repo to CircleCI, I have to perform the following steps to give it Git permissions

`Settings > Checkout SSH keys > Create and push user key`

This will create a new key for the GH user and then if the repo has a dependency that is directly pulling from a private git repository (using `git+ssh://...`), it will work.

What I would like to do is add a global deployment/user key once so that whenever I enable a new project I don't need to create a new SSH key.

Is this possible with CircleCI?

My project is using node.js, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

This is not possible. I would suggest adding a [feature request](https://circleci.com/ideas/).

To be honest, StackOverflow isn't the best place for this type of question. [CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com/) is a much better place.